# Kafka Consumer Properties - Is there any relationship between the container property ACKMODE and enable.auto.commit?

Tags: spring-kafka

If we set the consumer container property 'AckMode' to RECORD, enable.auto.commit to true and leave the auto.commit.interval.ms with default value 5000 ms, does the consumer commit the offset after getting a record based non the ACKMODE setting or will it commit the offset after 5000 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#committing-offsets) on the matter:

> Several options are provided for committing offsets. If the enable.auto.commit consumer property is true, Kafka auto-commits the offsets according to its configuration. If it is false, the containers support several AckMode settings (described in the next list)

So, if the `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true`, no one `AckMode` has effect: everything is done by Apache Kafka client itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: We generally recommend not using `enable.auto.commit` because it is less deterministic when the offsets are committed; the preferred ack modes are `BATCH` and `RECORD`. Starting with version 2.3, we default auto commit to false (unless explicit configured).

Comment: I've a question here - I've set enable.auto.commit to true and auto.commit.interval.ms to 10,000 (i.e., 10 sec). Now my question is - If the consumer gets 100 records when it first polled and the listener is processing one-by-one record and it processed only 80 records in 10 sec, does it commit and advance the offset by 80 or 100?

Comment: No, all of that. For consumer it doesn't matter how you process pulled records. It is just some commit process on background. More over the commit fully doesn't matter at runtime: consumer is always going to give you a next set of records. There is some internal index in the consumer. The committed offset has a value over restart.